# After clearing cache and localForage (IndexedDB) getting an error on loading the page

Tags: html, caching, indexeddb, localforage

DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.

After refreshing the page works perfect. this is happening only the first time loading the page (after clearing cache and IndexDB).

How IndexedDB is connected to cache?

will appreciate any help! thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention. It happens only in chrome

Comment: Code or it doesn't happen. Edit: let me rephrase. Paste your code or a link to a jsbin so that we may help debug.